# Facebook Like button at the bottom of a non-scrolling page

Tags: javascript, css, facebook-like

I have a web application that doesn't scroll and I have a facebook button at the button. Chrome and Firefox behave differently, but they both get it wrong.

Chrome repositions the div (good) but once you close the widget it doesn't go back to the bottom. Firefox doesn't reposition the div and the comment flyout is mostly hidden.

Is there any way I can get this to work? I don't mind hiding the comment flyout, but I've tried and Chrome repositions the viewport of an `overflow: hidden` div.

Check it out here
http://jsfiddle.net/KaZkL/

To reproduce, like and then dislike.

Chrome 15.0.874.121 MacOS X

[image]

Firefox 8.01 MacOS X

[image]

Comment: Works allright for me in Chrome 15

Comment: Duopixel, I am not seeing this problem in the latest versions of Safari or Firefox on OS X.

Comment: To reproduce, like and then dislike.

Comment: liked, disliked, still no flyout. (Chrome, Mac OS X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved in this way:

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget iframe.fb_ltr {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -70px;
}
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/bitliner/UtJ35/
The little dialog box appear just above the like button.

Hope this help.

Comment: Finally! Thank you so much Giovanni. I'd give you a million upvotes if I could. For my case I had to use `bottom: 35px` as my like button has an avatar and a site description.